# Using Countifs to Count One of Two Comments in One Column Based on the Value of Cells in Another Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns that I am looking at in this example. Column `F28:F86` which is labeled Error Severity and Column `G28:G86` labeled Error Occurrence. I felt like this would be a simple `COUNTIFS` formula to get the result I was looking for and to this point it has not been.

I have also tried variations of `SUMPRODUCT`, `IF(Vlookup(Countif`, etc. Here is the example:

```
Error Severity    Error Occurrence
Critical          Yes
Critical          Mgmt Find
Standard          Yes
Standard          No
Standard          Mgmt Find
Critical          No
```

The desired effect is as follows, Count if Error Severity is Standard and Error Occurrence is Yes or Mgmt Find. These tally in another cell that is used for a score card that gives us a percent of errors for the employee. It was working fine when I just used `COUNTIFS` function and was only counting if the error was standard and occurrence was yes, but when my director had me add the Mgmt Find I put that as a third criteria which is when it stopped working. The two versions of `COUNTIFS`, 
 I tried were:

```
COUNTIFS($F$28:$F$86,"Standard",$G$28:$G$86,"Yes",$G$28:$G$86,"Mgmt Find")

COUNTIFS($F$28:$F$86,"Standard",OR($G$28:$G$86,"Yes",$G$28:$G$86,"Mgmt Find"))
```

Then I started trying various other ideas with no success to this point. Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Sorry...the error severity and occurrence were supposed to show as columns for an example. for some reason it changed when I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can array the criteria and sum:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($F$28:$F$86,"Standard",$G$28:$G$86,{"Yes","Mgmt Find"}))
```

This basically does two COUNTIFS and SUMS the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to count the pairs of conditions separately and then add their results:

```
=COUNTIFS($F$28:$F$86,"Standard",$G$28:$G$86,"Yes")+COUNTIFS($F$28:$F$86,"Standard",$G$28:$G$86,"Mgmt Find")
```